# How to queue FBConnect graph requests to support resume in iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I am developing an app with iOS FBConnect library.

My app will post stuff one at a time to FB using graph requests, for example post a msg or post image.  I also need to wait for response as I am saving post IDs for later.

The question I have is this:
If I'm in middle of an upload, for example posting a large image to FB through request, but if user clicks "home" button to put my app in background.

If upload takes longer than what Apple allows before freezing my app, then I would like to save this and resume it once user comes back to the app.

Also, I would like to queue post operation in case internet is not available.  So that when internet becomes available, then upload it to fb and get postIDs.

What is the best way to achieve queue/resume?